# Mutiple Regression for Multiple dependent variables by using stats model

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have one dataframe having multiple independent variables (say ind_var['X1','X2','X3','X4']) and multiple data frames having different number of dependent variables (say dep1["y3,'y4;..'y10']). I have 100 of such data frames for dependent variables where column names and count of dependent variables are not fixed. I want to run regression for each dependent variable (preferably using the stats model) and save the intercept, beta ,p value and adj R2 in a dataframe.

any help would be highly appreciated

Currently i am doing it one at a time as below:
model=sm.OLS(Y1,ind_var).fit()

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.